# Как правильно сохранить данные в $_SESSION?

Tags: php, post

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {$_SESSION['search'] = $_POST['search']; $search = $_SESSION['search'];}
if (!isset($search)) { echo "Значение пустое" ;} else { echo "Значение ЕСТЬ! Вот оно : $search )))";}
```

Делаю **поиск** на сайте. Мне нужно сохранить **POST** переменную в которой хранится слово **поиска**, например "Телефон". Но данные не **сохраняются**. Где я допустил ошибку, и правильно ли хранить такие данные в сессии?

Comment: Данные в сессии сохраняются, но вы по какой-то непонятной причине к ним в своем коде не обращатесь

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Не хранят слово поиска в сессии. И не используют для поиска метод ПОСТ.

Поисковая строка передается методом ГЕТ и прекрасно доступна без всяких сессиий. Только к ссылкам надо её добавлять, например при постраничной навигации.

Answer (score 1):

Должно быть как-то так:

```
session_start();
if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
  $search = $_POST['search'];
  $_SESSION["search"] = $search;
} elseif (isset($_SESSION["search"])) {
  $search = $_SESSION['search'];}
} else {
  $search = "";
}
if ($search == "") { 
  echo "Значение пустое";
} else { 
  echo "Значение ЕСТЬ! Вот оно : $search )))";
}
```

В исходномм варианте происходило так что переменная заполнялась только при POST.